normal is always pointing the same way
I have an open topped cylinder with a material that is double sided in a Three.JS scene.
What I am trying to achieve is one color on the front of the cylinder, and another color on the inside of the cylinder.
To get this working I have created a new material class that extends THREE.MeshStandardMaterial, and I am modifying the vertex and fragment shaders in the onBeforeCompile hook.
at the end of the main method in the fragment shader I have this:
gl_FragColor = vec4(faceNormal.rgb, sampledDiffuseColor.w);

if(gl_FrontFacing == false) {            
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0, sampledDiffuseColor.w);

}

But for whatever reason that I can't really figure out, gl_FrontFacing is always set to true.
To my knowledge this is not something I am setting or modifying and it is something that webGL sets for me. But shouldn't it be false for all inside faces?
Or am I doing something wrong here?
To simplify it for myself I updated the onBeforeCompile hook
onBeforeCompile(shader: any) {
    shader.vertexShader = /* glsl */ `
    void main() {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
    `;
    shader.fragmentShader = /* glsl */`
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = gl_FrontFacing ? vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) : vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
    `;
}

and it shows up as red both inside and outside

OK, I figured out what causes it to always be the same.
I was creating the material with transparent: true. If I toggle that, then it correctly figures out what is inside and not.
Issue is that I do need that transparent feature as well
here is a full example that has transparent true, and non working inside color

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title> SimpleDoubleSide(gl_FrontFacing) </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
</head>
<body> </body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.160.0/three.js"></script>
<script>

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, 1, 0.01, 1000 );
camera.position.set( 1, 2, 3 );
camera.lookAt(0,0,0);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({  antialias: true });
const container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement ); 

renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setClearColor( 0xdedede, 1 );
const shMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { side: THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true } );

shMaterial.onBeforeCompile = shader => { 
    shader.vertexShader =
        `
    attribute vec2 backUV;
    varying vec2 vBackUV;
    ` + shader.vertexShader;
    shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace(
        `#include <fog_vertex>`,
        `#include <fog_vertex>
    vBackUV = backUV;
    `
    );
    shader.fragmentShader =
        `
    uniform sampler2D backTexture;
    varying vec2 vBackUV;
    ` + shader.fragmentShader;
    shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
        `#include <map_fragment>`,
        `#include <map_fragment>
    
    diffuseColor = gl_FrontFacing ? vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0) : vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0); //texture2D( map, vUv ) : texture2D( backTexture, vBackUV );
    `
    );
};

const cylGeom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0.5, 0.4, 1, 36, 8, true );
const cylinder  = new THREE.Mesh( cylGeom, shMaterial );
scene.add( cylinder );

render();

function render( ) {

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
}

</script>
</html>


found the solution outline in this github issue
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/25149

You should include the relevant code to fix the issue in the answer
